# Ruby Exponent Issue

Tags: ruby, math, algebra, exponential

When I run this script:

```
pi=3.14
NozzleAreaM=.005**2*pi.to_f
```

It returns 7.85e-05 instead of 0.000078 like it does on a normal calculator. I've looked everywhere and I can't find a fix to this problem.

Comment: Floating Point precision.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to tell ruby in what format you want to display the *float*:

```
pi = 3.14 
nozzle_area = 0.005**2  * pi

printf "%.8f \n", nozzle_area

--output:--
0.00007850
```

See prinf/sprinf here:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf

Note that displaying a float in a certain format does not affect how ruby stores the float internally.

Also, writing code like this is fine:

```
pi=3.14
NozzleAreaM=.005**2*pi.to_f
```

...as long as you never need to show your code to anyone else.  If you want to ask questions about your code, then you need to write legible code.  That means you should NOT cram every thing together with no spaces.

In addition, variables that start with a capital letter are constants in ruby.  If you do not know what that means yet, just live by this rule: do not capitalize any of your variable names.

Also, your pi variable is already a *float* (because it has a decimal point), so calling `to_f()` is unnecessary.

Also, ruby provides pi as a constant in the `Math` module(the Math module is required automatically):

```
nozzle_area = 0.005**2  * Math::PI

printf "%.8f \n", nozzle_area

--output:--
0.00007854
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been working on that forever.